# Send APDU command DISPLAY TEXT to USIM/SIM card by OTA-SMS

Tags: sms, apdu, ota, proactive

I send the command DISPLAY TEXT  to phone by using SMS-SUBMIT message. 
Why don't I get any text on my phone's screen?

details:

- My SMS-SUBMIT message
  according to ETSI TS 23.048, I don't use any security capabilities (no KIC, KID, RC/CC/DS)
- My DISPLAY TEXT command

D0 3F ; This is a proactive command of length 0x3f

81 03 01 21 81 ; The command is DISPLAY TEXT, high priority, wait for user

82 02 81 02 ; It was sent from the SIM to the display

8D 34 04 ; Encoding is 8-bit default SMS (ASCII), message:

48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 21 20 49 20 61 6D 20

; "Hello world! I am "

61 6E 20 61 6C 74 65 72 6E 61 74 69 76 65 20 53 49 4D

; "an alternative SIM"

20 54 6F 6F 6C 6B 69 74 20 73 74 61 63 6B 2E

; " Toolkit stack."

I merge SMS-SUBMIT and DISPLAY TEXT and send them on the SIM by SMS.
But I don't get any text on the screen of tne mobile phone.
Why?

Comment: There is not enough informations that may guide people to help you for. Please edit your question.